# Serializing the Dictonary to file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the Dictionary which contains the Tree Nodes.I have the form which will display the tree nodes in it.But when the session is expired and if the same form is opened the tree nodes will not be present in it.So I created the BinaryFormatter serializer to serialize the tree nodes to the file and save it.So when the same form is opened it will check for the file and deserialize the tree node objects in it and display even after session is expired.But the problem is with BinaryFormatter is it is too slow and it consumes lot of memory.So which is the best way for serializing the Dictionary in C#

Comment: Simplest way is not to serialize whole dictionary but serialize each element. This will allow you to reduce peak memory consumption.

Comment: is there any way we can serialize the tree node using json

Comment: We use Newtonsoft.Json for that